# Spring Boot application fails after adding @EnableResourceServer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I trying to create a resource server that will authenticate every request by validating the access token in the header. Whenever I add @EnableResourceServer on my application class the application fails to run. Once I remove the annotation above the application runs again. The error says I have no implementation of JAXB-API on my classpath.

Here is the code of my application class:

```
package com.example.oauthimplicit;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class OauthImplicitApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OauthImplicitApplication.class, args);
    }



    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/config").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.3.RELEASE')
    compile('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

When I run the application I get the following error:

```
2018-10-05 17:52:57.524  WARN 16921 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
2018-10-05 17:52:57.528  INFO 16921 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-10-05 17:52:57.574  INFO 16921 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-10-05 17:52:57.586 ERROR 16921 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.example.oauthimplicit.OauthImplicitApplication.main(OauthImplicitApplication.java:18) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.http.converter.jaxb.AbstractJaxbMessageConverter.<init>(AbstractJaxbMessageConverter.java:62) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.http.converter.jaxb.JaxbOAuth2ExceptionMessageConverter.<init>(JaxbOAuth2ExceptionMessageConverter.java:21) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.geDefaultMessageConverters(DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.java:117) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.<init>(DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.java:53) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.AbstractOAuth2SecurityExceptionHandler.<init>(AbstractOAuth2SecurityExceptionHandler.java:42) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint.<init>(OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint.java:36) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer.<init>(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer.java:62) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration.configure(ResourceServerConfiguration.java:118) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:230) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:321) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:92) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3d845712.init(<generated>) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:371) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$383bd88c.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$3(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$383bd88c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6f7b245e.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$383bd88c.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:278) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:421) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.http.converter.jaxb.AbstractJaxbMessageConverter.<init>(AbstractJaxbMessageConverter.java:59) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:276) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    ... 50 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Try adding jaxb-impl.jar together with jaxb-api

Comment: It does not work with jaxb-impl.jar

Comment: for me works with jaxb-impl.jar together with jaxb-api version 2.2.11

Comment: This not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

I've just fixed **the same** issue: after visiting the dependency page of (a quite new version of) Spring Security OAuth2 AutoConfigure (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth.boot/spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure/2.1.0.RELEASE) I decided to put/refresh all JAXB API related dependencies:

```
// Java 11
runtime('com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1')
runtime('com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.1')
runtime('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1')
runtime('org.javassist:javassist:3.23.1-GA')
```

Now it works fine, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 9 or higher you need to add this VM options in your Tomcat configuration

```
--add-modules
java.xml.bind
```

Answer (score 0):

I was following a Udemy course on CQRS and Event sourcing and the instructor create an OAuth 2.0 server but when i ran the auth server it kept failing with this error. i tried everything, the only thing that worked is adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.28.0-GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Without this i kept getting the exception

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]`

So thank you. I am totally new to spring boot and oauth 2.0 type implementation and i was trying to wrack my brains on it and knew it wasnt something that i did different from the instructor.. it somehow worked for him on an older version of spring and java 14 but i am on spring 2.5+ and java 16